# How to split string to characters in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am working on ciphering program, where ull put text and it will convert it into coded message. I stick and point where I dont know how to split len into sepparate characters. Is it even possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but we'll need to see your attempts at splitting a string into separate characters.

Comment: transfer function will do it for you. 
   

 `chars = transfer(string, mold = 'a', size = len(string))`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can split a string into a character array. If chararray = "abcdefg" then you can have an array like ca(1) = chararray(1:1), ca(2) = chararray(2:2) ...
ca(7:7) = chararray(7)

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in a do-loop using the iachar and achar functions.

```
program test
character*7 :: stringin
integer     :: single_character

stringin = 'message'

do i = 1, len(stringin), 1
    single_character = iachar(stringin(i:i))
    write(*,*) achar(single_character)
end do

end program
```

This creates an integer representation of the letters with iachar and converts them back with achar. This may be helpful if using a mathematical expression to do the encoding.

More information can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/IACHAR.html)